# How to customize TinyMCE button output

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I would like to change the default behavior of the indent button.  By default the indent button adds a css style `padding-left: 30px;` to the paragraph tag.  I would like to change that to `margin-left: 20px` or whatever number amount.

Comment: This is not possible without fiddling with the plugin code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible without hacking into tinyMCE code. One option might be using custom style as shown here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:style_formats

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Indented text', inline : 'p', styles : {marginLeft : '20px'}}
    ]
});
```

And then apply the style instead of pressing indent button.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented it a little differently though.  I ended up using formats http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats instead. Just because clicking a link was more analogous to pushing a button. `formats : {indent:{selector:'p', styles:{marginLeft:'20px'}}}` with a link `<a href="#" onclick="tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('indent');return false;">[Indent]</a>
<a href="#" onclick="tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('indent');return false;">[Unindent]</a>`

Answer (score 3):

The setting 'indentation' lets you configure the amount.
The option 'indent_use_margin' was added in January 2014 to let you switch the css attribute: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/pull/290

I needed this because we use TinyMCE to let users edit HTML emails and email clients (esp Outlook) are notorious about spotty CSS support.

Example:

```
    tinymce.init({
        indent_use_margin: true,
        indentation: 20,
```