# How to Customize TinyMCE HTML Output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-3

The theme for my site requires custom classes on HTML elements in order to display the styles properly (for example, the `ul`'s need to have the class `list-style`). I can't change the style for all `ul`'s because they are different on the site. I would like to be able to change the HTML, giving all of the `ul`'s that class for example, when you press the unordered list button (I can't use the styles dropdown). Where can I edit the plugin to change the HTML output for TinyMCE?

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416678/how-to-customize-tinymce-button-output

Comment: @nicovank I saw that question, but it will not work for my situation because I can't use the styles dropdown. Also, I don't want to edit the styles, I want to edit the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source of written markdown in tinymce. In there you wilk see the html tags and you can add your styles there. It is all achieved by this plugin. Please refer to docs for further information.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/